# C++ How to implement callbacks?

Tags: c++, callback

I'm trying to implement a `Button` class in C++. Here's how it's going so far:

`button.h:`

```cpp
class Button {
    private:
        unsigned short x;
        unsigned short y;
        std::string text;
        std::function<void()> onClickFunction;
    
    public:
        Button(unsigned short x, unsigned short y, std::string text, std::function<void()> onClickFunction);
        void onClick();
```

`button.cpp:`

```cpp
Button::Button(unsigned short x, unsigned short y, std::string text, std::function<void()> onClickFunction)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y
    this->text = text;
    this->onClickFunction = onClickFunction;
}

void Button::onClick()
{
    this->onClickFunction();
}
```

However, when I try to create a button, such as:

```cpp
this->toggleGridButton = Button(x, y, "Toggle Grid", &Engine::toggleGrid);
```

I get the following error:

> no instance of constructor "Button::Button" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (int, int, const char [12], void (Engine::*)())

How can I make a callback to a member function?

Comment: `std::function<void()>` doesn't fit for a class member function. Use a lambda function to initialize that member, you can capture the `this` pointer and any other class member variables as necessary there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Could you provide me some materials that can help me doing this?

Comment: You can use [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: Constructing a `std::function<void()>` using a non-static member function requires both the address of a member and a pointer to the object that provides context for calling that member.     Since you are constructing the `Button`, you can't simply provide the address of a member to construct the `std::function`.  There are various options - one is to provide a constructor that accepts a pointer-to-member (instead of the `std::function`) argument and does `this->onClickFunction = std::bind(this, member_fn_ptr)`.

Comment: First comment: only the conversion of the member function to the `std:: function` is relevant here. If you didn't know that, then you have scope to further narrow down problems when you meet them. This helps you write focused and specific questions, and also makes it much easier to find a solution just by searching. Try removing code until there's nothing left that isn't necessary to reproduce the same error, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Second comment: your interface doesn't tell the callback which button was pressed. You can store it as an argument with bind (or capture it in a lambda), but it might be nice just to pass as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
this->toggleGridButton = Button(x, y, "Toggle Grid", [this]() { this->toggleGrid(););
```